# Verb tense after almost

Tags: word-usage

I wonder how can I word the word almost plus verb. In other words, which verb tense should I use after almost?

Check the following examples and tell me which one is corrrect.

1. I almost do it yesterday
2. I almost done it yesterday

Considering that one person asked "Hey did you ask your girlfriend yet?"

And another person answered "No, But I almost ______ it yesterday!"

Where the blank, what should it go "done" or "do"?

Comment: The adverb **almost** requires no specific tense. The conjugation of the verb **to do** is available in your textbook and from many sources, such as [this.](http://en.bab.la/conjugation/english/do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of your example sentences are correct, because the action happened "yesterday" the verb tense needs to be in the past

> I almost *did* it yesterday.

Is the correct sentence.

Comment: Neither *is*, eh? ;-}

Answer (score 2):

"Done" is a confusing word, because it is technically present tense, but it talks about things in the past.

When a person has "done" something, they are in the state of having completed some task.

If you are looking for the actual past-tense of "do" the word is "did."

> I almost did it yesterday.